# Csv or excel file upload

Tags: jmeter

As part of my perfomance test i need to upload and submit `excel/.csv` files.

My flow is below.

```
1. Login
2. Create new account
3. Click on the upload button
4. Select excel or .csv file
5. Click on the submit button
```

I need to cover this using single jmeter script.

Please any one can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just record your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), the key points are:

1. Make sure to copy your csv/excel file(s) to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation - this way JMeter will be able to capture the upload request
2. Make sure to perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) of all dynamic parameters
3. Make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan

See [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide for comprehensive information on configuring JMeter for recording.

Comment: Hi Dmitri thanks for your help. But once i clicked on the upload button and its opened up third party window and asked to search file. How can i record that window?

Comment: JMeter acts on **protocol** level, all UI interactions required to search file happen solely on client side and you are interested in the file upload request